# Error in exceuting psql command using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am exceuting command through psycopg2 python but string formating automatically converting  column value to double quotes.

here is my code-

```
           list1=['abc','xyz']
           query = sql.SQL("select * from table  where column = {}")
           cur.execute(query.format(sql.Identifier(list1[0])))

           Error message- column "abc" does not exist
                          LINE 1: select * from table  where column = "abc"
```

I think postgresql does not take double quoted value but why it is automaticallly creating double quoted value, I am not getting it?

Comment: per the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) `sql.Identifier` will use double quotes _always_, it sounds like you might need [`sql.Literal`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Literal)

Comment: then how to get the results, how can i make it single quoted?

Comment: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Literal

Comment: YUP, got it, just have to replace identifier with literal